# I can't implement the test class - List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: unit-test, class

I was able to create a class that gets the data of an opportunity (the ID is passed by GET) and displays a form on a VisualForce page that allows sending an email with invoice attached...

Everything works fine, but when going from Sandbox to Production it gave me errors due to code coverage...

I'm trying to implement the test class but can't get past 48%...

[image]

My class:

```
public with sharing class pdfsendemail {
    public Account acc { get; set; }
    public Opportunity op { get; set; }
    public string eSubject{get;set;}
    public string eBody{get;set;}
    public string eDestinatarios{get;set;}
    public string htmlBody{get;set;}
    public String theOppID {get;set;}
    
    public pdfsendemail(){
        theOppID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

        op = [select id,AccountId,N_mero_de_pedido__c from Opportunity where Id = :theOppID];
        eSubject = 'Factura '+op.N_mero_de_pedido__c ;
        
        eBody = 'Estimado/a,<br/>Le adjuntamos la factura correspondiente al pedido número '+op.N_mero_de_pedido__c +'<br/><br/>Un saludo.';
       
        acc=[select Name,(select name,id,email from account.contacts where AccountId = :op.AccountId) from account where Id = :op.AccountId];//:ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id')];
        
        if(acc.contacts[0].Email!=null){
            eDestinatarios=acc.Contacts[0].Email;
            for(integer i=1;i<acc.Contacts.Size();i++){
                if(acc.contacts[i].Email!=null){
                    eDestinatarios+=';'+acc.contacts[i].Email;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public PageReference SendEmail(){
        Messaging.singleEmailMessage msg=new Messaging.singleEmailMessage();
        PageReference pdfexample=page.generatepdf;
        pdfexample.getParameters().put('id', theOppID);
        pdfexample.setRedirect(true);
        htmlBody = '<b>:eBody</b>';
        Blob b=pdfexample.getContent();
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment fa=new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        fa.setFileName('factura.pdf');
        fa.setBody(b);
        String eaddress;
        if(acc.contacts[0].Email!=null){
            eaddress=acc.Contacts[0].Email;
            for(integer i=1;i<acc.Contacts.Size();i++){
                if(acc.contacts[i].Email!=null){
                    eaddress+=':'+acc.contacts[i].Email;
                }
            }
            system.debug('-----------+1'+eaddress);
        }
        String[] toAddress=eDestinatarios.split(';',0);
        //toAddress.add(eaddress[i]);
        msg.setSubject(eSubject);
        msg.setPlainTextBody(eBody);
        msg.setHtmlBody(eBody);
        msg.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        msg.setFileAttachments(new messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{fa});
        //Now sending An email...
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] result=Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[]{msg});
        if (result[0].success) {
            ApexPages.Message resp = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm, 'Email enviado satisfactoriamente.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(resp);
            //System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        } else {
            ApexPages.Message resp = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Se ha producido un error al enviar el correo: '+ result[0].errors[0].message);
            ApexPages.addMessage(resp);
            //System.debug('The email failed to send: '+ result[0].errors[0].message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Test class:

```
@isTest
private class pdfsendemailTest 
{
    private static testMethod void SendEmail() 
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'AccountTest';
        acc.N_mero_de_cliente__c = '0046';
        insert acc;
        
        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName  = 'Fran';
        cont.LastName  = 'Bedia';
        cont.Alias__c = 'Fran';
        cont.Email = 'fran@demo.es';
        cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert cont;
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = '12/12/2022';
        opp.StageName = 'PEDIDO';
        opp.CloseDate = date.ValueOf('2022-12-12');
        opp.Fechacierre__c = date.ValueOf('2022-12-12');
        opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert opp;

        String rid = opp.id;
        
        test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.generatepdf;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',rid);
        
        //init controller 
        pdfsendemail objCtrl = new pdfsendemail();
        //Call pageRef mymethod
        PageReference   objPageRef =  objCtrl.SendEmail();
        
        //put system asserts
        
        System.assertEquals (null,pageRef);
        
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Never use hard coded IDs and always insert the data you need for a test in the test or test setup.

Comment: Fundamentally, unit tests cannot see data in your org (by default). Hard coding IDs may not work since IDs will vary between different orgs.

Comment: Also use "Test Data Factory pattern" so that you don't have to write same line of code again and again. https://www.apexhours.com/test-data-factory-in-salesforce/

Comment: Thanks! i change the hard coded ID... Now, I create the account, contact, and op in test class